# Google search result count for 10000 terms

Tags: java, search, google-api, google-search

I have a list of about 10000 names, and I want to determine in an automatic way their "importance". A sufficient metric for me would be the number of results of each name in Google.

Is there an easy way to get that number? I can see that by subscribing to the [Custom Search API](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) I only have a free quota of 100 searches per day. It will take me 100 days to get my results!

Is there some easy way to do this?

Thanks!

*Note: My language of preference is Java.*

Comment: It looks like the Bing API will let you do 7 queries/sec, so just half an hour. http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. Write it as an answer so that if it works for me I can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [Bing API](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper) will let you do 7 queries/sec, so just half an hour.

(Documented [here](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/API%20Basics.pdf) on the last page under the heading "What you must do")